# UnSubscribe an Amazon SNS topic using AWS Lambda fn with Topic ARN and Email address

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I want to send an unsubscribe request to SNS Topic for email, As I'm new to Lambda, Can you please let me know what function can be used here, I have email address and Topic arn as incoming parameter. Im using python 3.8 boto 3 .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In order to unsubscribe from a topic, you need the subscription ARN. Then you can use [`sns.unsubscribe`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sns.html#SNS.Client.unsubscribe). Example:

```
response = client.unsubscribe(
    SubscriptionArn='string'
)
```

If you only have the topic ARN and email address of your subscribers, then you need to find the subscription ARN. You can use [`sns.list_subscriptions_by_topic`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sns.html#SNS.Client.list_subscriptions_by_topic) for that. Example:

```
response = client.list_subscriptions_by_topic(
    TopicArn='string',
)
```

Then you can take the response (a list of subscriptions) and iterate through it to find a match to your given email address and use the subscription ARN to call the `unsubscribe` method as mentioned above. If the response does not contain your email address but there might be more subscriptions because `NextToken` from the response is not empty, then you need to use the `NextToken` value and provide it to your next request of `sns.list_subscriptions_by_topic`. Example:

```
response = client.list_subscriptions_by_topic(
    TopicArn='string',
    NextToken='string'
)
```

However, take care that it can take a while until you find the correct subscription ARN if there are thousands of subscriptions. In such a case I can highly recommend that you store the subscription ARN next to the email address somewhere, so it's easier to unsubscribe and you don't need to iterate over all subscriptions.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer, Will need to store the SubscriptionArn when i create the subscription.

Comment: Hi S.hesse, is there a way to get the SubscriptionArn in response when sending the subscription request because as of now im getting this "SubscriptionArn": "pending confirmation". Only when user confirms the subscription by the given link in the email subscriptionarn is getting formed.

Comment: Yes: you need to add `returnSubscriptionArn` in your `subscribe` request. See the docs here: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sns.html#SNS.Client.subscribe

Comment: does that mean we dont have to wait for user to click on the email link to confirm subscription? in response of subscription request we will get the arn?

also is there a way to confirm the subscription ourself only via lambda

Comment: You still need to wait for a user to confirm the subscription. But you can already retrieve the subscription ARN while the subscription is still pending. You can of course write a Lambda function that is subscribing someone with their email -> then you get the ARN in the response of `subscribe` but the owner of the email address still needs to confirm that they own this email address.

Comment: Hi S.Hesse, Is there a way i can store these email and subscriptionARNs in aws and later on i can retrieve from same whenever unsubscription call comes

Comment: I saw something like environment variables, can we push those email address and subscription ARNs dynamically there from the response

Comment: No, environment variables are the appropriate place to store these information. Rather store them in a DynamoDB table. You can use the email address as the `HashKey` and the subscription ARN as `SortKey`. Then, if someone wants to unsubscribe using their emails, look up the subscription ARN in the table.